# CLion not working for any file in another directory

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
libs/
  sdw/
  glm-0.9.7.2/
    glm/
    ...
src/
  ProjectName.cpp
```

The `sdw` directory is full of classes with `.cpp` and corresponding `.h` files. Inside any of these files, if I type `#include "` then it auto-suggests header files within this directory. Syntax highlighting also works for any included classes, as does suggestions for methods etc.,

However, inside `ProjectName.cpp`, I get no such suggestions for header files, and syntax highlighting plus method suggestions are not present. The only things that work are from the `std` lib like `vector` etc.

No files get any highlighting etc., for anything inside the `glm` directory.

Here is a relevant part of the `CMakeLists.txt` that was provided to me:

```
set(GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS libs/glm-0.9.7.2)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(libs/sdw)

add_executable(ProjectName
        libs/sdw/Utils.cpp
        libs/sdw/Triangle.cpp
        src/ProjectName.cpp)
```

- Inside files like `libs/sdw/Utils.cpp` I am doing: `#include "Triangle.h"`. This works.
- Inside `src/ProjectName.cpp` I am doing: `#include <Utils.h>`. This
  runs but does not work in the way I want, as described above.
- And in everything I am doing `#include <glm/glm.hpp>` which does not
  work in the way I want.

EDIT:
I noticed when opening CLion it promps me to clean the project when loading it. If I click OK then it gives me these errors:

```
No rule to make target 'all'.
Make execution failed with exit code = 2
No compilation commands found
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleted `.idea` and selected CMake project this time (chose Makefile last time)